# how to run two dialog boxes simultaneously in bash?

Tags: bash, user-interface

i am writing a bash script to show both `--gauge` and `--tailbox` dialog boxes at the same time in active mode. using `--and-widget` enables me to show both boxes on same window but facing following problems:

1) `--guage` appear 1st, complete its process, then `--tailbox` appear (should appear simultaneously?)

2) scroll bar does not appear in `--tailbox` to see previous outputs?

my code is:

```
(
# infinite while loop for --gauge
while :
do
echo $counter
    (( counter+=step ))
    [ $counter -gt 100 ] && break
    sleep 1
done
) & (
  # loop for --tailbox 
  for i in {1..100000}
  do 
      echo -e $i >>log
  done 
) | dialog --begin 0 5 --title "Progress" --gauge "" 8 70 0 --and-widget --begin 8 5 \
      --title "Log" \
      --tailbox log 15 70
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's long time ago. Anyway...got the same challenge. 
You can try this:

```
for i in {1..100}
do 
  echo $i >> log && echo -e $i && sleep 1
done | dialog --begin 7 5  --no-shadow --title "Log" --tailboxbg log 25 130 \
              --and-widget \
              --begin 1 5 --no-shadow --title "Progress" --gauge "" 5 130 0
```